# The error occurs when creating Openshift Cluster on AWS with IPI

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift

We are trying to creating Openshift Cluster looking at this website.

https://keithtenzer.com/openshift/openshift-4-aws-ipi-installation-getting-started-guide/

We run "create cluster" but installation is failed.
The Error is following.

> ERROR Attempted to gather ClusterOperator status after installation failure: listing ClusterOperator objects:
> Get "https://api.xxxxx.openshift.yyyyy.private:6443/apis/config.openshift.io/v1/clusteroperators":
> dial tcp: lookup api.xxxxx.openshift.yyyyy.private on aa.bbb.c.d:ee: no such host
> ERROR Bootstrap failed to complete: Get "https://api.xxxxx.openshift.yyyyy.private:6443/version":
> dial tcp: lookup api.xxxxx.openshift.yyyy.private on aa.bbb.c.d:ee: no such host
> ERROR Failed waiting for Kubernetes API. T

We made openshift.yyyyy.private in Public Hosted Zone with Route53 before installation but it seems that api.xxxxx.openshift.yyyyy.private is NAME_RESOLUTION failed.

What should we do to complete installation?

Comment: OpenShift requires an `authoritative domain name server` when you install OpenShift with Public Hosted Zone. So, you need to register your domain in AWS Route 53 first.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! We haven't recognized that we have to resister domain before installation. We'll check it and resister our domain.